# Flexigrid doesn't work with jQuery 1.4.3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, flexigrid

I am trying to use flexigrid plugin for jquery, the problem is that I also want to use the plugin fancybox, and this plugin uses jQuery 1.4.3, but flexigrid doesn't seem to work with that version of jquery.

When I roll back to the old jquery version that comes with flexigrid the grid does work but fancybox doesn't.

This is the code i am using:

```
        $("#grid1").flexigrid
        (
        {
        url: 'php/get.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        colModel : [
            {display: 'ID', name : 'id', width : 40, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
            {display: 'Name', name : 'name', width : 180, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Email', name : 'email', width : 120, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'tID', name : 'tid', width : 130, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Active', name : 'numcode', width : 80, sortable : true, align: 'right'}
            ],
        buttons : [
            {name: 'Add', bclass: 'add', onpress : doAction},
            {separator: true},
            {name: 'Delete', bclass: 'delete', onpress : doAction},
            {separator: true},
            {name: 'Activate', bclass: 'activate', onpress : doAction},
            {separator: true},
            {name: 'Deactivate', bclass: 'deactivate', onpress : doAction},
            {separator: true}
            ],
        searchitems : [
            {display: 'Name', name : 'name', isdefault: true}
            ],
        sortname: "id",
        sortorder: "asc",
        usepager: true,
        title: 'XXX',
        useRp: true,
        rp: 15,
        showTableToggleBtn: true,
        width: 700,
        height: 200
        }
        );
</script>
```

And the php response looks like this:

```
{
page: 1,
total: 3,
rows: [
{id:'28',cell:['28','test','test','test','1']},
{id:'27',cell:['27','test','test','test','1']},
{id:'26',cell:['26','etrer','ter','trt','0']}]
}
```

I am using firebug and it doesn't show any js error.

Is there a way to use flexigid with jquery 1.4.3?

Comment: what errors does it give, or did you figure this out ?

Comment: if you must not use jQuery i will recommend ExtJs for your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try rendering your JSON using double quotes, not single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Both plugins seems to work with v1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

I think I have both plugins working with jQuery 1.6.1. Obviously it depends on both [flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/) and [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) jQuery plugins and an example JSON file that I have called `flexigrid.json`. If you download those plugins and make sure the `src` and `href` links to the correct locations for the JavaScript and CSS and create a file called `flexigrid.json` with the following content:

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "total": 3,
  "rows": [
  {"id":28,"cell":[28,"test","test","test",1]},
  {"id":27,"cell":[27,"test","test","test",1]},
  {"id":26,"cell":[26,"etrer","ter","trt",0]}]
}
```

**Note:** The JSON in your example is not valid (as @Josh pointed out already). You can run in through [an online parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) to see the errors.

Here is the example page with both plugins:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="flexigrid/js/flexigrid.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="flexigrid/css/flexigrid.pack.css"/>
    <script src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            function doAction() {}

            $("#grid1").flexigrid({
                url: 'flexigrid.json',
                dataType: 'json',
                colModel : [
                    {display: 'ID', name : 'id', width : 40, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
                    {display: 'Name', name : 'name', width : 180, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'Email', name : 'email', width : 120, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'tID', name : 'tid', width : 130, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'Active', name : 'numcode', width : 80, sortable : true, align: 'right'}
                    ],
                buttons : [
                    {name: 'Add', bclass: 'add', onpress : doAction},
                    {separator: true},
                    {name: 'Delete', bclass: 'delete', onpress : doAction},
                    {separator: true},
                    {name: 'Activate', bclass: 'activate', onpress : doAction},
                    {separator: true},
                    {name: 'Deactivate', bclass: 'deactivate', onpress : doAction},
                    {separator: true}
                    ],
                searchitems : [
                    {display: 'Name', name : 'name', isdefault: true}
                    ],
                sortname: "id",
                sortorder: "asc",
                usepager: true,
                title: 'XXX',
                useRp: true,
                rp: 15,
                showTableToggleBtn: true,
                width: 700,
                height: 200
            });

            $("a#example1").fancybox({
                'titleShow'     : false
            });

            $("a#example2").fancybox({
                'titleShow'     : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
                'easingIn'      : 'easeOutBack',
                'easingOut'     : 'easeInBack'
            });

            $("a#example3").fancybox({
                'titleShow'     : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'none',
                'transitionOut' : 'none'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="grid1"><tr><td></td></tr></table>

<p>Different animations - 'fade', 'elastic' and 'none'<br />
    <a id="example1" href="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4058/4252054277_f0fa91e026.jpg">
        <img alt="example1" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4058/4252054277_f0fa91e026_m.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a id="example2" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2489/4234944202_0fe7930011.jpg">
        <img alt="example2" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2489/4234944202_0fe7930011_m.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a id="example3" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2647/3867677191_04d8d52b1a.jpg">
        <img alt="example3" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2647/3867677191_04d8d52b1a_m.jpg" />
    </a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** This will not work locally when testing in Chrome 13 due to the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) security restriction. You can see the error in the console *Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin*. You will need to serve to the example page and JSON from a proper web server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same issue. I found the below links helpful to get started.

Core issue - from groups.google.com 
"As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error,  the request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of  JSON data for this reason. JSON is a data-interchange format with  syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object  literal notation. For example, all strings represented in JSON,  whether they are properties or values, must be enclosed in double-  quotes. For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/. 
Basically you have to be careful with your json now, and ensure its  formatted correctly. I would guess its related to this. Check the  json.org site and check your JSON to make sure its correct."

http://simonwillison.net/2006/oct/11/json/

http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#jsonformatter